# classes have same interface but the type of parameter is different

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism, template-meta-programming

I have a class TypedNode to store some data:

```
template <typename Type>
class TypedNode {
 public:
  TypedNode() {}
  void SetNodeData(Type data) { data_ = data; }
  Type GetNodeData() { return data_; }

 private:
  Type data_;
};
```

Then I can use it:

```
int main() {
  TypedNode<int> int_node;
  TypedNode<double> double_node;
  TypedNode<Vector3d> vector3_node;

  int_node.SetNodeData(1);
  double_node.SetNodeData(2.3);
  vector3_node.SetNodeData(Vector3d(4,5,6));;
}
```

But I want to define a function to access then:

```
void Access(std::list<TypedNode> node_list) {
  for (auto node : node_list) {
    node.GetNodeData();
    // if it is an integer, do one thing
    // if it is a double, do another
  }
}
```

The list needs a concrete class, But I need to store any type of nodes.

Some I changed the code of Node:

```
class NodeBase {
 public:
  NodeBase() {}
};

template <typename Type>
class TypedNode : NodeBase {
 public:
  TypedNode() {}
  void SetNodeData(Type data) { data_ = data; }
  Type GetNodeData() { return data_; }
 private:
  Type data_;
};

void Access(std::list<NodeBase> node_list) {
  for (auto node : node_list) {
    node.GetNodeData();
    // if it is an integer, do one thing
    // if it is a double, do another
  }
}
```

But the Access() function can only call the methods of Base class.
Despite every derived class have one same name interface SetNodeData, They have a different type. So they are different. They cannot override one same interface in the Base class.

What can I do?

==============================================================

This is my solution:

```
#include <list>
enum NodeType {
  kInt,
  kDouble,
  kVector3,
};

class NodeBase {
 public:
  NodeBase() {}

  virtual int GetDataInt();
  virtual double GetDataDouble();
  virtual Vector3 GetDataVector3();
  NodeType type() const { return type_; }

 protected:
  void set_type(NodeType type) { type_ = type; }

 private:
  NodeType type_;
};

class NodeInt : NodeBase {
 public:
  NodeInt() { set_type(kInt); }
  int GetDataInt() override { return data_; }
  double GetDataDouble() override { check(false) << "error"; }
  Vector3 GetDataVector3() override { check(false) << "error"; }

 private:
  int data_;
};

class NodeDouble : NodeBase {
 public:
  NodeDouble() { set_type(kDouble); }
  int GetDataInt() override { check(false) << "error"; }
  double GetDataDouble() override { return data_; }
  Vector3 GetDataVector3() override { check(false) << "error"; }

 private:
  double data_;
};

void Access(const std::list<NodeBase>& node_list) {
  for (auto node : node_list) {
    switch (node.type()) {
      case kInt: {
        int data = node.GetDataInt();
        // do something about int
        break;
      }
      case kDouble: {
        double data = node.GetDataDouble();
        // do something about double
        break;
      }
      case kVector3: {
        Vector3 data = node.GetDataVector3();
        // do something about Vector3
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not require the types themselves to support a `Print()` function?

Comment: `std::cout << node.GetNodeData();` 'node.GetNodeData() doesn't look like a member of `NodeBase` class. does it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Print() is not a good example. So I edit the question.

Comment: @虞坤霖 Best you provide a [MCVE] to give a full picture of your problems.

Comment: you have two Access function mentioned in your question.  `void Access(std::list<NodeBase> node_list)` and  `void Access(std::list<TypedNode> node_list)` is that a typing mistake?

Comment: @Yucel_K yes. And I don't know where should I define it.

Comment: @虞坤霖 Templates can also be specialized for particular types.

Comment: @Yucel_K The code is just an example to show what I want. So the code I post cannot compile now. What I want is, I can access all node using same interface. And I can do different things to every type of node.

Comment: "I need to store any type of nodes." Then you should design an interface which is common to all types of nodes. `GetNodeData` cannot be a part of it. Note you can ask a different question, for example "I need to store nodes of types that belong to this known in advance, finite, rigidly fixed set of types", in which case the answer would be different.

Comment: @Yucel_K the next one is the second version of the first one

Comment: @虞坤霖 yea i get that but in the question i dont see any `GetNodeData();` implementation in the `NodeBase`. so you want GetNodeData to be derived from `NodeBase` and override it `TypeNode` ?

Comment: @Yucel_K yes. But I can not define virtual template function in the Base class.

Comment: perfect. just wanted clarification. u might want to edit and add `GetNodeData();` to you nodebase class for others.

Comment: your code `list<NodeBase>` involve object slicing, it would not work.

Comment: and please [edit] with any constraint you have.

Answer (score 6):

Your `TypedNode` template provides no apparent value, it is just a getter and a setter of encapsulated data so it is better to eliminate it for simplicity. What you seem to need is a type that can be `int`, `double` or `Vector3d` so those can be held in same container. For that there is [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) in C++17. People with substandard compilers can use [Boost.Variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/variant.html) that is basically same, just works with C++98 too.

```
#include <variant>

struct Vector3d {int x, y, z;};
using Node = std::variant<int,double,Vector3d>;
```

Sure, you can have `std::variant<TypedNode<int>,TypedNode<double>,TypedNode<Vector3d>>` when there is some vital functionality in it. Posted `TypedNode` had no functionality, other but more bloat to type.

For accessing variant using same interface there are several ways. For example it can be done using a visitor. Here is a visitor `NodeOutput` for `ostream` output of every type in `Node`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct NodeOutput {
    std::ostream& os_;
    NodeOutput(std::ostream& os) : os_{os} {}

    void operator()(Vector3d const& v3) 
    {
        os_ << "Vector3d (" << v3.x <<", "<< v3.y <<", "<< v3.z <<")\n";
    }
    void operator()(double const& d) {os_ << "Double " << d <<"\n";}
    void operator()(int const& i) {os_ << "Int " << i <<"\n";}
};
```

Using such visitor we can write `operator<<` for `Node`:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Node const& v) {
    std::visit(NodeOutput{os}, v);
    return os;
}
```

Trying it out. The `std::list` is rarely used container so here it is replaced with `std::vector` for simplicity, but it will work similarly with other containers.

```
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    nodes.emplace_back(42);
    nodes.emplace_back(6.66);
    nodes.emplace_back(Vector3d{3,2,1});

    for (auto& n: nodes) {std::cout << n;}   
}
```

Output:

```
Int 42
Double 6.66
Vector3d (3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you basically want to access the overridden functions of the `NodeBase`. You can still do that with templates. I am not going to suggest code changes on your design because i assume that you oversimplified this to give us an idea of what you want your code to do.

With that said, let's assume that `NodeBase` class is the base class for `NodeInt` and `NoteDouble`. and it looks something like this (slightly simplified compared to yours).

```
    class NodeBase
{
public:
  ...
  virtual void DoSomething()
  ...
};

class NodeInt : public NodeBase
{
public:
  ...
  virtual void DoSomething() //overridden
  {
  }
  ...
};

class NodeDouble : public NodeBase
{
public:
  ...
  void DoSomething()//overriden
  {
  }
  ...
};
```

Let's also assume that our Access function looks like;

```
template<typename Type, typename A>
void Access(std::list<TypedNode<Type>, A> node_list)
{
  for (auto node : node_list)
  {
    node.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Note that our Access function can now take any type of list containing`TypeNode` because of `TypedNode<Type>`

The job of the Access function is just to call the DoSomething. it shouldn't care what type it is. and it should be deduced based on what to call depending on what we pass as an argument to the Access call.

- if a list passed to `Access` is a type `<TypedNode<NodeBase>` you
  want each node to call, `NodeBase::DoSomething();`
- if a list passed to `Access` is a type `<TypedNode<NodeInt>` you want
  each node to call, `NodeInt::DoSomething();`
- if a list passed to `Access` is a type `<TypedNode<NodeDouble>` you
  want each node to call, `NodeInt::DoSomething();`

To do this, first Instead of inheriting from Base class, lets inherit from a parameterized template argument.

```
template<typename Type>
class TypedNode : public Type
```

Next, we want to declare and define the `DoSomething` function for our `TypedNode` class.

```
template<typename Type>
class TypedNode : public Type
{
  ...
   void DoSomething();
  ...
};

template<typename Type>
inline void TypedNode<Type>::DoSomething()
{
   Type::DoSomething();//this is where the magic happens.
}
```

Notice the `Type::DoSomething();` this will allow us to call `DoSomething()` function of the Generic Base class. One thing to pay attention to is that when we initializing an object using template arguments,  the class that is used in the template argument initialization has to have a class member named `DoSomething` otherwise during compilation we will get an error.

for example;

```
 TypedNode<int> intNode;      //wont work because int doesnt have a member DoSomething.
 TypeNode<NodeBase> baseNode; //fine.
 TypeNode<NodeInt> intNode2;  //fine
```

finally, the main code that produces the outcomes for us.

```
int main() 
{
  std::list<TypedNode<NodeBase>> baseNodeList;
  std::list<TypedNode<NodeInt>> intNodeList;
  std::list<TypedNode<NodeDouble>> DoubleNodeList;

  TypedNode<NodeBase> baseNode;
  TypedNode<NodeInt> intNode;
  TypedNode<NodeDouble> doubleNode;

  baseNodeList.push_back(baseNode);
  intNodeList.push_back(intNode);
  DoubleNodeList.push_back(doubleNode);

  Access(baseNodeList);
  Access(intNodeList);
  Access(DoubleNodeList);
  return 0;
}
```

here is the full code  https://ideone.com/2jEmBO

Comment: I'm very glad you answer my question. But, my point is: the node_list[0] is NodeInt, node_list[1] is NodeDouble, node_list[2] is NodeVector.

Comment: @Rubik if that's the case yes, you can  go along the lines of the answer of Öö Tiib.its better then writing your own Variant class